# Extracting numbers from cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to extract X and Y from 2021-08-26 06:10:03,1,"",X,Y, which is in a cell in excel. X and Y can be either one, two, or three digit numbers. I want to extract X and Y from thousands of rows with the date and time different on each row. How can I do this?

Comment: You mind sharing few more examples here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 current channel you can use this formula (where your data are in column A):

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1:A100,","),4,5)
```

It first splits your data into single parts/cells based on the comma.
Then it takes the 4th and 5th part (which could be one, two or three digit numbers - that's for this approach irrelevant).

UPDATE:
Without `Textsplit`

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[position()=4 or position()=5]")
```

`Filterxml` builds a XML-string from which we take the 4th and 5th tag.

To return two columns (instead of two rows):

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[position()=4 or position()=5]"))
```

Comment: I do have Excel 365 but I get #NAME? returned...

Comment: Then you are not on the current channel :-(

Comment: Added a formula that should work without current channel - but looks more complex

Comment: Alright, thought that might be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: That worked! But I only get the X-value. Is it possible to get X and Y in two different columns?

Comment: Did you copy the `position() =5` as well - or did your base data change? `2021-08-26 06:10:03,1,"",X,Y` - within this example X is the part 4 and Y is part 5 based on the comma as a separator

Comment: I copied as you wrote it. There is a comma-sign after Y if that matters.

Comment: Can you post one life example - as for me your example from the question returns X and Y.

Comment: 2021-08-26 06:01:03,1,"",0,0,

Comment: This returned 0

Comment: And 2021-08-26 09:51:03,1,"",35,1, returned 35 etc

Comment: What is your language? For me it works: https://i.imgur.com/ii5F8zA.png (German Excel -therefore the comma in the formula is a semicolon)

Comment: Swedish, so I had to change some commas to semicolons for it to work. If I copy your code exactly then it doesn't work. But still I only get X

Comment: `=FILTRERAXML("<t><s>" &BYT.UT(A1;",";"</s><s>") & "</s></t>"; "//s[position()=4 or position()=5]")` - this should be the swedish variant (used this link: https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/) ...

Comment: Ah I get the same as you. My mistake. Is it possible to get the numbers in two different columns instead of two different rows?

Comment: I already added that to the answer - you have to use `TRANSPOSE`

Comment: Yeah now everything works! Thank you!!! Life saver!

Comment: Great. As you're new on SO: please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)